# My convolution code stops working after the full overlap. Any suggestions?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

```
%in1 = input('Enter the input sequence:');
%in2 = input('Enter the impulse sequence:');

x= [1 2 3];
h= [1 1 1];

if length(in2)>length(in1)
    x= in2;
    h= in1;
end

c= zeros(1,length(h)+length(x)-1);
w= length(h);
h= flip(h); h=[h, zeros(1,(length(x)+length(h)-2))];disp(h);
x= [zeros(1,w-1), x, zeros(1,w-1)]; disp(x);disp(w);

for n=1:length(x)-(w-1)
    c(n)= sum((h(1+n-1):h(w+n-1)).*(x(1+n-1):x(w+n-1)));disp(c);
    h= circshift(h,1);disp(h);disp(x);
end
```

I've tried checking at what point it stops. It's after the 'h' completely overlaps 'x'. But Before that it works just as expected. I'm not sure what I'm missing here because the logic seems sound.

This leads me to believe maybe I'm missing some sort of syntax or not in full control of MATLAB.

```
     c= 1     0     0     0     0


     h= 0     1     1     1     0     0     0

     x= 0     0     1     2     3     0     0

     c= 1     3     0     0     0


     h= 0     0     1     1     1     0     0

     x= 0     0     1     2     3     0     0

     c= 1     3     6     0     0


     h= 0     0     0     1     1     1     0

     x= 0     0     1     2     3     0     0

    %At this point I just get zeros

     c= 1     3     6     0     0


     h= 0     0     0     0     1     1     1

     x= 0     0     1     2     3     0     0

     c= 1     3     6     0     0
```

Any Clue?

Comment: Why do you pad `h`? Don’t do that!

Comment: Despite the the question if you should pad or not pad, have you considered to use break points and see what exactly happens inside the for-loop? Please read [How to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)